# How to draw 10 min High low prices at opening

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I tried to draw the highest and lowest price lines for the 10-minute range of the daily trading opening (9:30 - 9:39 EST).

Here are my code:

```
indicator("10 Min Opening", overlay = true)
// import PineCoders/VisibleChart/4         (Do not use yet)
var int _minutes_elapsed = na
var float _hh = na
var float _ll = na
var float _midle = na
var line _hLine = na 
var line _lLine = na
var line _midLine = na
var int _x1 = na

if hour(time) == 09 and minute(time) == 30
    _hh := 0
    _ll := 500
    _midle := 0
    _x1 := bar_index
if hour(time) == 09 and minute(time) >= 30 and minute(time) <= 39
    _hh := math.max(_hh,high)
    _ll := math.min(_ll,low)  
    _midle := (_hh + _ll) / 2
    _minutes_elapsed += 1
    _hLine := line.new(_x1 ,_hh,bar_index ,_hh, xloc = xloc.bar_index,color = color.green)
    _lLine := line.new(_x1  ,_ll,bar_index  ,_ll, xloc = xloc.bar_index,color = color.green)
    _midLine := line.new(_x1  ,_midle,bar_index  ,_midle, xloc = xloc.bar_index,color = color.green, style = line.style_dashed)
    _hLine.set_y1(_hh),_hLine.set_y2(_hh)
    _lLine.set_y1(_ll),_lLine.set_y2(_ll)    
    _midLine.set_y1(_midle),_midLine.set_y2(_midle)    
    _hLabel = label.new(bar_index + 20  ,_hh,"H= " + str.tostring(_hh),color=color.green,style= label.style_none,textcolor=color.green,size = size.normal,textalign = text.align_right)    
    _lLabel = label.new(bar_index + 20  ,_ll,"L= " + str.tostring(_ll),color=color.green,style= label.style_none,textcolor=color.green,size = size.normal)    
    _midLabel = label.new(bar_index + 20  ,_midle,"Mid= " + str.tostring(_midle),color=color.green,style= label.style_none,textcolor=color.green,size = size.normal)    
    label.delete(_hLabel[1])
    label.delete(_lLabel[1])
    label.delete(_midLabel[1])
if bar_index > bar_index[1] 
    _hLine.set_x1(bar_index),_hLine.set_x1(bar_index)
    _lLine.set_x1(bar_index),_lLine.set_x1(bar_index)
    _midLine.set_x1(bar_index),_midLine.set_x1(bar_index)
```

However, I encountered some issues with the results.

1. The line was supposed to start at 9:30, but it started at 9:39 instead.
2. I set the label text-align to be aligned at the right, but it seems like it's not working.
   Can someone assist me in fixing these errors?
   Thank you so much.

HL line at 10 min Opening range:

[image: HL line at 10 min Opening range]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `xloc = xloc.bar_index`. Try `xloc =` [xloc.bar_time](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_xloc.bar_time)

Somelike that this:

```
_hLine := line.new(timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 9, 00, 00) ,_hh,timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 9, 30, 00) ,_hh, xloc = xloc.bar_time,color = color.green)
```

Comment: cannot work, only correct for last day, previous day draw to many line!